# Нет возможности обновиться на мажорную версию windows через службу обновлений не прибегая к графическому интерфейсу?

Tags: windows, api, cmd, powershell, update

Не срабатывают ни usoclient startscan, ни обращения к API агента обновления, разнообразные скрипты автоматизации (poweshell, vbs и т.д.), ни сброс агента обновлений.

Обновление на 1803 не находится, но зато как только нажать в Центре обновления кнопку "Проверка наличия обновления" оно сразу находится и даже автоматически начинает загружаться.

По журналу вижу, что происходит обновление агента

```
{9FE4ED35-16F6-40ED-A1DB-3991A25F25E8} 2018-05-13 17:53:03:813+0700 1 147 [AGENT_DETECTION_FINISHED] 101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 0 0 UpdateOrchestrator Success Software Synchronization Windows Update Client successfully detected 0 updates. uGov/8FTF0C8GAgV.0.1.0.0.3.0
{3F1EF19A-B4B7-4518-9AC2-92A9729770FB} 2018-05-13 17:53:06:376+0700 1 147 [AGENT_DETECTION_FINISHED] 101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} 0 0 UpdateOrchestrator Success Software Synchronization Windows Update Client successfully detected 1 updates. uGov/8FTF0C8GAgV.0.1.0.0.4.0
{6374AC37-8838-49ED-8384-D01C2CB3412D} 2018-05-13 17:53:06:861+0700 1 167 [AGENT_DOWNLOAD_STARTED] 101 {F8EE1E09-5379-44DF-B86D-E49E70CBE43B} 1 0 UpdateOrchestrator Success Content Download Download started. uGov/8FTF0C8GAgV.1.1.1.2.0
```

Но почему этого не происходит например при использовании модуля PSWindowsUpdate?

Comment: Решение нашлось? А то в СП Микрософта, предлагают за 2485р установить через их инженеров))

Comment: Пробовал найти изменения в системе по разнице образов. Нашел, но только изменения, понять по ним, что именно их вызывает не смог. Было подозрение на задачи в шедулере, но они не подтвердились. Через какое то время обновление таки появляется само. Но как спровоцировать его так и не понял. Т.ч. пока при необходимости скачиваем через например [http://download.wsusoffline.net/] и накатываем сами.